# Google Docs Script Error - Unterminated string literal. (line 4)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

working on using a formula ive been using for a while to find distances between addresses as a function to get around the 50 import xml limit in google spreadsheets. - the import xml string works just fine as a formula in google docs however i keep getting the "Unterminated string literal. (line 4)" error  when i debug, the only way i have found to get it to clear is to delete everything between the inner () . Any help or ideas would be most appreciated.

```
function findkm(c) { 
  var y = 0;

  y = INDEX(SORT(ImportXML("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xmlorigin="&c&"&destination="&d&"&sensor=false&units=metric";"//distance");1;FALSE);1;2);
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `c` and `d` are variables and this whole thing is a function call, try replacing `&` with `+` and `;` with `,`. Something like this:

```
y = INDEX(SORT(ImportXML("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xmlorigin="+c+"&destination="+d+"&sensor=false&units=metric","distance"),1,FALSE),1,2);
```